# Why getting "No module named 'PIL'" in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

when I run the little application of kivy in pycharm. I got this error:
  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe 
    "C:/PycharmProjects/PYTHON TUTORIAL/free.py"

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\user\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-06-
30_41.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC 
v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, 
img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not befound.
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib fromlist=
[modulename], level=0)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
```

please I need your help.

Comment: You do not have the PIL (Pillow in Python 3) library installed. Install it using pip and everything should work fine: `py -3.6 -m pip install pillow` (CMD)

Comment: i'm getting this error:                                                                          
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage 
    [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
    Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' File 
    "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
 32\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
 EventLoop.ensure_window()
@FJSevilla

Comment: Did you install the dependencies before installing kivy? `py - 3.6 -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew`. See https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation

Comment: **thanks in a million, it worked.** @FJSevilla

Comment: please is there free ide for python to publish for windows application(GUI)? @FJSevilla